# Could not find openssl in backend

Tags: server, rust, openssl, client

Error I get:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `openssl` in `backend`
  --> ...\src\...\swagger-0.12.1\src\connector.rs:41:34
   |
41 |             native_tls::backend::openssl::TlsConnectorBuilderExt::from_openssl(ssl);
   |                                  ^^^^^^^ could not find `openssl` in `backend`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `openssl` in `backend`
  --> ...\swagger-0.12.1\src\connector.rs:85:34
   |
85 |             native_tls::backend::openssl::TlsConnectorBuilderExt::from_openssl(ssl);
   |                                  ^^^^^^^ could not find `openssl` in `backend`

   Compiling hyper v0.2.1
error: expected identifier, found `"rustc-serialize"`
   --> ...\hyper-0.2.1\src\lib.rs:129:14
    |
129 | extern crate "rustc-serialize" as serialize;
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected identifier
```

Generated a server stub user swagger. Ran into issues where cargo couldn't find openssl, giving an error like 'custom build something openssl-sys 0.9.24'. This was a known issue and I overcame it by downloading vcpkg, and using vcpkg to download openssl. Then using environment variables to point to the download folder so cargo could use openssl. But now the error seems to be that `openssl` doesn't exist in `backend`?

It also seems to specific to windows, any ideas?

Tried changing the version of native-tls to the most up to date version but it doesn't seem to have an affect at all. It looks like swagger's dependencies need updating but I literally just generated this stub...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've landed on a flaw from the Rust documentation tools; it picks up what is in a package, but doesn't show the limits.

The `backend` module definition is defined as:

```
#[cfg(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "ios"))]
pub mod security_framework;

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
pub mod schannel;

#[cfg(not(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "windows", target_os = "ios")))]
pub mod openssl;
```

In other words, the situation is the following:

- If you are on linux (i.e. not macOS, not windows, not iOS), then `openssl` is available
- If you are on windows, then `schannel` is available
- If you are on MacOS or iOS `security_framework` is available

You should, however, not be trying to target a specific backend, as this defeats the purpose of the library. Instead of importing `native_tls::backend::openssl::TlsConnectorBuilderExt`, import `native_tls::TlsConnectorBuilder` and let it decide what backend you need.

This may be easier said than done, however, since by the looks of your error this is caused by a third-party library, which indicates that it was only tested on Linux.

Comment: The error is due to the swagger codegen being only tested on Linux. But nothing should stop OP from fixing generated code.

Comment: @Cerberus that is true, although it may require a bit of work depending on how he used it. I was waiting for more information to be able to advise further :-)

Comment: Turns out the issue is documented, but the focus of the project is on keeping the ability to add root CAs rather than cross-platform needs; this would be an ideal time to fork & expand.

Comment: I updated the swagger version and the error no longer comes up. Apparently it was fixed in the v1. something... It is annooying how swagger doesn't generate the latest versions beacuase now that I have updated the swagger version, I am getting several errors edue to depereciated code. thanks all for looking into this.

Comment: @theBigCheese88 I much prefer (and contribute to!) `openapi-generator` due to this. I see more risk than value in having `build.rs` generate your code from `swagger`, preferring it to do it manually & test against it. Obviously, your mileage (and use case) may vary.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld yes. I gave up on Swagger Codegen for generating rust code since it didn't seem to be updated. openapigenerator seems to be better, cheer! https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Comment: @theBigCheese88 I have a PR on that repository to add an async `reqwest` module for codegen; if you want the async version, by this point my branch should be safe for general use. Glad you found your solution, even if it didn't end with the starting libraries :-)